# How to handle the response of Volley in Android

Tags: android, request, android-volley

I use volley in the Android Activity, and make a request and got the response, but I want to handle the response maybe in an another method,but it won't work, what should i do ?

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

RequestQueue queue;

private String result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String url = "www.google.com/something/I/need";

    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Do something with the response
                    Log.i("resp", response);
                    // I want to do sth with the response out of here
                    // maybe like this, let result = response
                    // and see the log at the end of the code
                    // but it failed, what should I do?
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // Handle error
                    Log.e("error", error.toString());
                }
            });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
    Log.e("result", result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Volley requests are asynchronous, so the program after sending the request, continues execution without waiting for the answer. So the code that processes the result is inserted into the OnResponse method. For more precise help explain why you would like to log out of the method OnResponse

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you're doing: You're creating a `StringRequest`, then you add it to the request queue, but then you immediately try to check the result. Obviously, this won't work because the request hasn't been processed yet.

Your response will arrive in the `onResponse` method, and only then you'll be able to do something with it. You can set `result = response` here, but you'll only be able to see the value when the `onResponse` is called which could take some time.

Hope this clarifies things.